# Comma Usage using Titles

Tags: commas

My sentence is as follows:

> Carol Ohmann discusses in her article *Daisy Miller: A Study of Change in Intentions* how the main heroine of Henry James' novella brings rise to arguments.

Do I have to set the title of the article off in commas or leave it as it is written?

Comment: Move the prepositional phrase to the front and put a comma after it.  **“In her article ‘Daisy Miller: A Study of Change in Intentions’, Carol Ohmann discusses how the main heroine of Henry James’s novella gives rise to arguments.”**  Still a weak sentence, though. Try Writers.SE maybe.

Comment: If it's an article, it should be in quotes instead of italics; italics are for books (but _Daisy Miller_, being a book, **should** be italicized -- i.e, "_Daisy Miller:_  A Study of Change in Intentions"). Commas are your choice; [if you say them, and want your readers to hear them](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/178994/15299), put them in. Otherwise not.

Comment: Commas imply that Carol has only ever written this one article, or that the article has previously been mentioned, but not its title. If neither is the case, leave them out.

Answer (score -2):

I'm hesitant to say they are required, but I'd suggest commas on each side for clarity. Also, as tchrist said, the overall structure is a little awkward.